# How to specify which input goes to which form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have rows of data where each column is a `<td>` that contains an `<input>`. The challenge is when the user pushes the submit button, I want 2 forms to be submitted, with differing inputs. How can I specify in the input which form that input should go to?

The reason this is funky is because normally, you'd have this:

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

So the input goes to whichever form it's nested within. But in my case, since it's impossible to do this kind of teasing out because I need:

```
<form1>
<form2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input1 /></td>
      <td><input2 /></td>
      <td><input2 /></td>
      <td><input1 /></td>
      <td><input1 /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form1>
</form2>
```

If there is no way to make the above work except to do something like the below:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <form1>
        <td><input1 /></td>
        <td><input1 /></td>
        <td><input1 /></td>
      </form1>
      <form2>
        <td><input2 /></td>
        <td><input2 /></td>
      </form2>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

That's also an acceptable answer. I'd just prefer to avoid the above because ironically from a UX perspective, it makes the most intuitive sense to mix up the inputs across the forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't achieve this without splitting your inputs in 2 distinct `form`s as you already mentioned **or** without using `javascript`. Well, the third option would be to "separate" forms on the back-end by their names (`form[1][name]`, `form[2][name]`, etc.)

Comment: +1 
Form elements can not be nested: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element.

Answer (score 0):

Submit the two groups of inputs you want via JavaScript. If you are using jQuery:

```
var group1 = $('#myform :input').not('.group2').serializeArray();
var group2 = $('#myform :input').not('.group1').serializeArray();

// post each group wherever you want 
$.post("/page1", group1);
$.post("/page2", group2);
```

https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/